# Accessing iOS iCloud app data from a Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud

I want to peek around where I'm not supposed to, specifically, I want to have a look at what "documents & data" is being stored in iCloud by some of my apps. I can see them in Manage Storage on the iCloud preference pane, but not in `~/Library/Mobile Documents` or anywhere else on the system. The app is iOS only, does this mean that the Mac doesn't store this data, or have I just not found it yet?

Comment: My iOS app data can be seen on Mountain Lion’s Mobile Documents without Bendim’s method. They are just there. Are you using Lion?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Go to the `~/Library/Mobile Documents` folder. Type anything in the search field in your Finder window. Make sure that Mobile Documents is selected in the Search bar, not This Mac.

Next, click on the **+** icon, and choose **Kind is Document**. Go back to the search field and erase what you typed. Now all your iCloud documents will display.

Click on **Save**, and check **Add to Sidebar** to add this search to your Finder window sidebars.

[image: Searching "Mobile Documents"]

*Note: one submission said to type a period (.), and, while this starts the search, this may not find all your documents if extensions are not visible. So it's best to start a search, then choose Kind is Document and delete the search.*

Comment: It's empty - not finding anything. The only app that's in there is an empty folder for soundhound, not the other two iCloud apps that appear in "Manage Storage".

Answer (score 1):

### [Cloud Mate](http://www.rwe-uk.com/app/cloud-mate)

Eurgh, second time I've found myself promoting this app… but it works… I used it to fix an issue with an iOS iCloud app… although it shows the documents folder by default you can click on the path list at the bottom to get "up" a directory.

Anyhow it's called Cloud Mate:

> Drag and drop files in and out of iCloud, between applications, all in a single familiar finder-like interface.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Go to the ~/Library/Mobile Documents folder on mac.

Comment: How does this improve on Bendim's answer